# What is the limit of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

What is the limit of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k+1}$

Can anybody help me with that? Any hints on what series whose limit is known I can simplify this to?

Comment: Try expand $ln(1+x)$ and put $x=1$.

Comment: @user121270 You should post that as an answer.

Comment: It's too short for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We [know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) that $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x^n=\frac{1-x^N}{1-x\quad}$ . For $|x|<1$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}x^N=0$, so $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ .

Integrating both sides, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n=-\ln(1-x)$, which, for $x=-1$, yields the desired

result. Of course, it should be noted that before being able to apply the formula, we must first prove

the convergence of the [alternating harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Alternating_harmonic_series) using either [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) or [Leibniz's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k+1} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 x^kdx = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^kdx = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{1}{1+x}dx = Ln(1+x)|_{x=0}^1 = Ln2$